# What is the id of easysearch.input?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I am trying to make an if statement in js that goes off of an html input field, but it is not a normal input field.  It is implemented with easy search, a meteor package.  this means there is no declaration of an id value, so I cannot call the input by .getElementById() or at least I do not know how.  Can anyone help me? here is a link to easy search: https://github.com/matteodem/easy-search-leaderboard

Comment: just pass `id` to the `EasySearch.Input`

Comment: can you show me what that would look like please? @corvid

Comment: `{{>EasySearch.Input id="some-id" index=index}}`

Comment: @corvid you should put this as an answer so I can give you the best answer... thanks!!!